# When will struct packing issues crop up?

Tags: c++, struct

I have been reading about struct bit packing order problems but I have not come across it myself due to limited exposure. However, I note that those discussions were mostly for very complicated applications.

I am now writing a struct to hold information from ifstream like such

```
struct MyFileStruct
{
    char data1[40];
    int data2;
    char data3[12];
    // etc..
};

ifstream fin;
// .. snip ..
fin.read((char*)&myfilestruct, sizeof(MyFileStruct));
```

And just thought if in this simple scenario whether any problems will surface, maybe in another OS or 32/64 bit architecture. etc. So, exactly, when will bit packing order be a consideration?

Comment: Packing generally only becomes a concern or problem when you try to serialize data lazily and pretend that C data structures are laid out exactly the same as your desired serialization format (which generally they aren't).

Comment: The perhaps most likely concrete example of a real system that cannot read your files isn't because of packing, it's because things break just as badly when your little endian files are read on a big endian system (or vice versa)

Comment: Bit packing is not relevant until you start to use bit fields.  Member alignment would be more relevant with your snippet, at least as long as you make your data1 length not divisible by 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packing rules (and, similarly, the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)) could become a consideration, **including with your example**, when

- The program is compiled with a different compiler
- The program is compiled with a different version of the same compiler *(theoretically)*
- The program is compiled with different compiler options, including but not limited to changing the target OS, target hardware, or 32/64 bit settings
- Compiler directives are added to the source code, such as `#pragma pack`.

A safe general rule is that **your code is only guaranteed to work if the executable reading your struct was written by the same executable**.

When this is a concern, one common solution for packing issues (but not endianness) is to use non-standard compiler directives to remove packing at the cost of efficiency.

This can be done with [`pragma pack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for Microsoft compilers and [`__attribute__ ((__packed__))`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) for gcc.

Comment: Generally, different versions of the same compiler retain compatibility with each other.  You don't mention 'compiled on a different type of hardware' (e.g. IA32 vs SPARC or PPC or ARM).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good point.  I didn't consider that _same target OS_ can still be interpreted as _different hardware_.  Edited.

Answer (score 3):

With that specific struct, the issue you're most likely to encounter is endian-ness. On a little-endian system, the lowest-addressed byte of that `int` contains the *least* significant 8 bits. On a big-endian system, the *most* significant 8 bits.

Therefore if you write the bytes of that struct to a file on one kind of system, transfer the file to the other kind of system, and read it back, then you'll see a different value in `data2`.

There are other issues that you could encounter with other structs, though, or with unusual systems/compilers:

- size of the basic types - `int` is generally 4 bytes but is not required to be. `long` is of different sizes on different common systems (4 bytes on Windows, 8 bytes on 64 bit Linux). Obviously if you try to read a struct from a file, and expect a different number of bytes from what was actually written by some other C++ implementation, you have a problem.
- padding - the compiler is allowed to put unused bytes into the structure between members. This generally happens in order to ensure alignment. For example in many compilers, the offset of an `int` member is always a multiple of 4. Since 40 is a multiple of 4 anyway in your struct this wouldn't make any difference, but if the first array was 39 bytes then an implementation that aligns `int` would insert an unused byte, and one that didn't would not. On some CPUs (for example x86) it is helpful but not essential that `int` be aligned, in which case compilers commonly have ways to annotate a structure to say whether or not to pad it.

Since these kinds of differences exist, it is not legitimate in general to write a struct directly to file (or socket). You can get away with it in the specific case where whoever reads it has exactly the same memory representation for that struct, which means that you can do it if you first work out exactly what bytes go where with what meaning, and then ensure that all programs that need to read/write the file can work with that format.

Answer (score 2):

A typical example where you'd run into problems is if you serialize an array of structures. Let's say the structure size is 12, but it's packed either to 4-byte boundaries or to 8-byte boundaries.  If you have an array of 2 elements on disk, the first one will start at offset 0 either way.  The second one will start either at position 12 (if you're packing to 4-byte boundaries) or at position 16 (if you're packing to 8-byte boundaries).  So when you read the array, the first element will come in right, but the second one (and subsequent ones) may be messed up.

Note that in Visual Studio, the default packing is to 8-byte boundaries for both 32- and 64-bit compiles, so you might get lucky and not have problems.  But if you wanted to see this, set your 32-bit compile to compile with alignment to 4-byte boundaries and your 64-bit compile to align to 8-byte boundaries (for example).  Then create an array of structs as in the previous paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule is that you can read a file that you wrote with code compiled by the same compiler (and that includes compiler options). The simplest form of this is a program that writes out binary data so that it can later read it back in. Beyond that, you're into implementation-specific behavior, and there's no simple answer.